# Unable to tokenize sentences using gensim and nltk in python

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, tokenize, gensim

I have a list of titles:

```
> print(data)
> 
  0   Manager
  1   Electrician
  3   Carpenter
  4   Electrician & Carpenter
  ...
```

I am trying to use gensim to find the closest related titles.

The code I have is:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import nltk
import gensim
from gensim import corpora, models, similarities
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 

df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')
corpus = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Job Title'])
tokenized_sents = [word_tokenize(i) for i in corpus]

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(tokenized_sents, min_count=1)

model.most_similar("Electrician")
```

When I am running tokenization to tokenize each title as a sentence  (tokenized_sents variable), it only tokenizes the header:

```
> tokenzied_sents 
> [['Job', 'Title']]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over a `pd.DataFrame`, it returns it's *columns*:

```
In [9]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10, (10,3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [10]: df
Out[10]:
   a  b  c
0  0  7  3
1  5  0  5
2  7  7  9
3  2  0  0
4  6  9  2
5  8  5  2
6  5  0  2
7  3  2  5
8  4  8  6
9  0  5  1

In [11]: [c for c in df]
Out[11]: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I think you probably want:

```
[word_tokenize(i) for i in corpus['Job Title']]
```

Since you want to iterate over the values in the column `'Job Title'`, so:

```
In [12]: [c for c in df['a']]
Out[12]: [0, 5, 7, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 4, 0]

In [13]: [c + 10 for c in df['a']]
Out[13]: [10, 15, 17, 12, 16, 18, 15, 13, 14, 10]
```

Although, you could probably just dispense with `pandas` altogether, since `gensim` tends to work with lazy streams, and you are just using `pandas` to read a csv files, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I am able to iterate using corpus['Job TItle'][i], however, when I am getting to model.most_similar("Manager"), I get an error 'word 'Product Manager' not in vocabulary'. Where would I specify the vocabulary?